# select input data from table based on the existing variant type of object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

In my project I have a problem that I find in a table where I go to select types of `intervention`. There are interventions that are unique, others that have variants. The problem arises when the selection of the variant (for example) `c`, the intervention with the variant of type `a` is always obtained.
Starting from the beginning I have a `class` of this type:

```
export class Intervention {
    id: number
    code: string
    description: string
}
---------------------------------------------
import { Intervention } from "./intervention"

export class AssociationIntervention {
    id: number
    intervention: Intervention
    price: number
    variant: string
    variants?: string[] //used for contain all variants
```

An example of present data in Intervention is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `intervention` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `intervention` (`id`, `code`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'A', 'good'),
(2, 'B', 'ok'),
(3, 'C', 'no');
```

An example of present data in AssociationIntervention is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `association_intervention` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `intervention_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  `variant` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `association_intervention` (`id`, `intervention_id`, `price`, `variant` ) VALUES
(1, 1, 22.16, NULL),
(2, 2, 18.17, 'a'),
(3, 2, 32.15, 'b'),
(4, 3, 10.29, NULL);

ALTER TABLE `association_intervention`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FKc9gs2ok9kwfp1b7l1r0lvaapu` FOREIGN KEY (`intervention_id`) REFERENCES `intervention` (`id`),
```

The table on my page looks like this:

```html
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="colgroup">Code</th>
          <th scope="colgroup">Price</th>
          <th scope="colgroup">Select</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let type of interventionVar; index as i">
          <tr *ngFor="let variant of type.variants; index as j">
            <td>{{type.intervention.code}} - {{type.variants[j]}}</td>
            <td>{{type.price[j]}}</td>
            
            <td>
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" (click)="press(type, j)">
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

The method in `ts` is this:

```
interventionVar: AssociationIntervention[]
selectedElement: AssociationIntervention[] = []

press(selected: AssociationIntervention[], variant: number) {
    const newInterv = Object.assign({}, selected)
    this.selectedElement.push(newInterv)
    console.log(this.selectedElement[0])
}
```

The problem is that even if with the above data I went to select intervention `B - b`, I would always select intervention `B - a`. How can I solve?

Comment: Is interface `AssociationIntervention` the same as `InterventionAssociation` ?

Comment: @OwenKelvin writing mistake. I edit immediately. There is only AssociationIntervention

Comment: If you can share the exact interfaces code that would be better, Just copy and paste the interface into your question. Also share where you are assigning the values of the properties

Comment: @OwenKelvin i edit the post with accurate data of interface and database

Comment: You have called `selectedElement.push()`. Please confirm the type for `selectedElement`? Is it `selectedElement: AssociationIntervention` or `selectedElement: AssociationIntervention[]`

Comment: @OwenKelvin i edit the post, I couldn't push without arrays

Comment: I have made a simple stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9lu3hl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts . What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: @OwenKelvin `variants` is `= [null]` if there isn't a `variant` in the Association, is not always k and j

Comment: You didn't do anything with `variant` parameter of `press()`.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc yeah i know, I entered it because I wanted to understand if I could use it to solve the problem

Comment: So what you called `B - b`, `B - a`, `a` and `b` here is from `variant` field, not from an element of `variants` array?

Comment: variants is ['a','b'] if there is a and b variant. Variants is [null], if there isn't a variant

Comment: a-b and j-k are confusing the question nothing else... Will be easier if you can, put the expected scenarios and what you are currently getting. Using the stackblits which you shared. like `press(type: B, 0)` should return `someObject` and `press(type: B, 1)` should return `null`. if possible break the questions into...description, problem, expected | current, methods you tried... I think a proper structure can be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

try to find all the variants list first. and find the corresponding intervention of each variant associated with. The following code helps you find that.

[stackblicks solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-comk3p?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  interventionVar: AssociationIntervention[] = interventionVar;
  selectedElement: AssociationIntervention[] = [];
  allVariant = {};
  selectedValues;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.allVariant = this.getAllVariants();
  }

  getAllVariants() {
    let items = {};
    associationIntervention.some(x => { 
      x.variants.some(y => { 
        if(y && items[y]) {
            items[y].push(x.intervention_code);
        }else if(y){
          items[y] = [];
          items[y].push(x.intervention_code);
        }
      });
    });
    return items;
  }

  keys() : Array<string> {
    return Object.keys(this.allVariant);
  }

  press( variant: string) {
    this.selectedValues = this.allVariant[variant];
  }
}
```

[stackblicks solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-comk3p?file=src/app/app.component.html)